# Scala - Finatra - Reading ip address from header

Tags: scala, finagle, finatra

I'm new to Finatra and scala. I need to store the ip address with another data in a post request. I'm using a custom case class:
`case class MyRequest(name : String, email: String)`
How can I also get remoteAddress in this request?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find it in the [document](http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/build-new-http-server/controller.html#requests), you can implement your case class looks like this:

```
case class MyRequest (
  request: Request,
  name : String,
  email: String
)
```

and the `request` is the type of `com.twitter.finagle.http.Request`, so you can access remoteAddress in this way:

```
post("/[your-api]") { r: MyRequest
  val ip = r.request.remoteAddress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't. If your request type is a custom case class. Probably you can do something like the following, and use jackson for deserialisation the request to your own case class:

```
  post("/{your-api-path}/") {
    r: Request =>

      val remoteIP = r.remoteHost
      val myRequest = objectMapper.readValue(r.contentString, classOf[MyRequest])
      ...
  }
```